# Python multi-line string losing formatting

Tags: python, list, text-based

I am making a hangman game, which gets the hangman shape from a list. For some reason though, because each image is in a multiline string, somehow it loses formatting so that one line goes on the same as another.

Here's the code:

```
    '''

     ___________.._______
    | .__________))______|
    | | / /      ||
    | |/ /       ||
    | | /        ||.-''.
    | |/         |/  _  \
    | |          ||  `/,| #this line!
    | |          (\\`_.'
    | |          -`--'
    | |          |   |
    | |          |   |
    | |          |   |
    | |          | _ |
    | |          
    | |          
    | |          
    | |          
    | |         
    """"""""""""""""""""""""|
    |"|"""""""\ \       '"|"|
    | |        \ \        | |
    : :         \ \       : :  
    . .          `'       . .'''
```

Obviously, where it say's '#this line!', that's the one that moves up. I can provide the rest of the list if required.

Thanks! :)

Comment: eh, don't understand the question... Some code would be nice...

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the \ (backslash).

Clarification: the line before the line that moves up ends in a '\', this character has special meaning, if you escape it by adding another '\' it will work properly, so change it to '\\'.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you can do is to define your string as a **raw** string:

> a = **r**'''
>
> ...
>
> '''

Note the 'r' character before the string definition